# Parse the relative link and absolute link using python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Its a project for downloading images, audios, videos etc .
But in some sites, i found there is no full link. Just relative path.
So I dont know how to get those relative links.

My full project is in:

```
https://github.com/MuneebKalathil/MaD
```

This is my example link , I want to download all images from this link . There are thumbnail images , But i dont want that images . If you click the thumbnails , It will Go to  original Image page . I want to download that images

```
http://www.ragalahari.com/actress/14035/kajal-aggarwal-at-memu-saitham-dinner-with-stars.aspx
```

Some part of the source is:

```
<tr>
<td id='pagingCell'>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align='center'><div id='galdiv' style='float:center;margin-right:3px;;margin-bottom:3px'>
<a href='/actress/14035/kajal-aggarwal-at-memu-saitham-dinner-with-stars/image1.aspx' ><img src="http://imgcdn.raagalahari.com/nov2014/starzone/kajal-agarwal-memu-saitham/kajal-agarwal-memu-saitham1t.jpg" alt="Kajal Aggarwal" title="Kajal Aggarwal at Dine with Stars Memu Saitham"></a>
```

And , I want to get a relative link address first:

```
/actress/14035/kajal-aggarwal-at-memu-saitham-dinner-with-stars/image1.aspx
```

and find it's absolute path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define the base url, find all `img` tags and, if the `src` attribute value does not start with `http`, use [`urlparse.urljoin()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin) to join the base url and `src`.

Example, using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'http://www.ragalahari.com'
url = 'http://www.ragalahari.com/actress/14035/kajal-aggarwal-at-memu-saitham-dinner-with-stars.aspx'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content)

for img in soup.find_all('img', src=True):
    src = img.get('src')
    if not src.startswith('http'):
        src = urljoin(base_url, src)

    print(src)
```

Prints:

```
http://icdn.raagalahari.com/images/ragalaharilogo.png
http://www.ragalahari.com/images/helpicon.png
http://www.ragalahari.com/images/rssicon.png
http://www.ragalahari.com/images/twittericon.png
http://www.ragalahari.com/images/facebookicon.png
http://www.ragalahari.com/images/searchicon.png
http://imgcdn.raagalahari.com/nov2014/starzone/kajal-agarwal-memu-saitham/kajal-agarwal-memu-saitham1t.jpg
http://imgcdn.raagalahari.com/nov2014/starzone/kajal-agarwal-memu-saitham/kajal-agarwal-memu-saitham2t.jpg
http://imgcdn.raagalahari.com/nov2014/starzone/kajal-agarwal-memu-saitham/kajal-agarwal-memu-saitham3t.jpg
http://imgcdn.raagalahari.com/nov2014/starzone/kajal-agarwal-memu-saitham/kajal-agarwal-memu-saitham4t.jpg
...
```

Update (part of the code for getting `a` links):

```
for a in soup.select('div#galdiv a'):
    link = a.get('href')
    if not link.startswith('http'):
        link = urljoin(base_url, link)

    print(link)
```

Comment: Can u please write the code in python3 .. getting some error :(

Comment: this program only getting image links . i want href link near src links too

Comment: @MuneebK do you mean regular `a` links?

Comment: @alexce ,  i wwant the absolute links of </actress/14035/kajal-aggarwal-at-memu-saitham-dinner-with-stars/image1.aspx> ..  i edited the question.. :) .. new to python  :(

Comment: thatss working ... :D... can i contact u if i hav more doubts ?.. aany fb , gmail or yahoo ?

Comment: well .. one mor e doubt , this is just an example url .. So if i give any other url from diferent website .. will it work ? . you used select('div#galdiv a'): .. so hope it will work only for this .. Really thank you for your help

Comment: @MuneebK instead of `select('div#galdiv a')` you may just use `find_all('a')` if you need all links on the page. Hope that helps.

Comment: @MuneebK just replace `soup.select('div#galdiv a')` with `soup.find_all('a')`. Should do the trick.

Comment: @MuneebK oops, sorry, should be `soup.find_all('a', href=True)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`urllib.parse.urljoin`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin). Pass, as its first argument, the URL of the page. As its second argument, pass the `href` or other possibly-relative URL. It will correctly deal with absolute and relative URLs, resolving them to the final absolute URL.

If you are still using Python 2, `urljoin` is in the `urlparse` module.